# My <td>s are too low and i have no idea why

Tags: html, css

I'm building a website and I have 3 `<td>`s. I didnt put `padding-top` or something but it says I have padding there and I have no idea how to fix it. Any idea?

Here's a screenshot

[image: Here's a screenshot]

Comment: Did you reset the default browser padding

Comment: Browser built-in padding

Comment: First, add proper code of your page, may be create a fiddle or some other way, anyways try setting this css: `html, body{padding:0;margin:0;}` should help some., but problem may be somewhere else.

Comment: already fixed it ty anyway

Comment: Just used vertical-align: top;

Answer (score 0):

Fixed: Used `vertical-align: top;`